# ASP.NET Core | Pomelo MySQL | Scaffolding works via Console, but no connection via Code

Tags: mysql, docker, asp.net-core

I just started coding a new small program for my company which is using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql to connect to the company's database.
I built the scaffolds of the tables via the console which worked fine.
But I'm not able to get a connection out of my code to the database using the same connection string as when I was scaffolding through the console.
I checked the permissions of the database and the user I'm using to access has all permissions (including connections from every host).

Eventually nice to know: The MySQL database is running in a docker container (linux) as well as my application, while my system is running Windows 10. I easily get a connection to the database via the scaffolding script and via MySQL-Workbench.

My connection string: 
`Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=XXX;User=XXX;Password=XXX;`

The error message I'm getting:

```
MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs
MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs
MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(Nullable<IOBehavior> ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable<IOBehavior> ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(bool errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, bool buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, CancellationToken, Task<ExecutionResult<TResult>>> verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable<T>+AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+AsyncIterator<TSource>.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor<T>+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator, Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Project_Gunther.Controllers.SevUsersController.Index()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Do I need to make any connections for the port to access the database from my docker container in the other container?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Greetings Felix

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/780798 ? Have you inspect the root cause exception?

Comment: That actually seemed to have fixed the problem as far as I'm getting a connection to the database now. Thanks a lot @stukselbax !